# Mathml equations are overlapping due to Negative margin

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mathjax, mathml

I am using mathjax to convert mathml in svg.
my input html is given below.
When i convert below into svg by using mathjax process queue, It generate output with negative margin. Due to that mathml equations overlap to each other.

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
      <script type="text/javascript"
              src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
      </script>
    <style>
    body {
    font-size: 2em;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div><math display="block" alttext="" data-uri="" altimg-width="460" altimg-height="90">
     <mrow>
      <mtable>
       <mtr>
        <mtd columnalign="left">
         <mtable>
          <mtr>
           <mtd>
            <mtext>
             reactants
            </mtext>
            <mo>
             →
            </mo>
            <mtext>
             elements
            </mtext>
           </mtd>
           <mtd columnalign="right">
            <mtext>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </mtext>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">
             Δ
            </mi>
            <msub>
             <mrow>
              <mi>
               H
              </mi>
             </mrow>
             <mrow>
              <mn>
               1
              </mn>
             </mrow>
            </msub>
            <mo>
             =
            </mo>
            <mo>
             –
            </mo>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">
             ΣΔ
            </mi>
            <msubsup>
             <mrow>
              <mi>
               H
              </mi>
             </mrow>
             <mrow>
              <mtext>
               f
              </mtext>
             </mrow>
             <mrow>
              <mo>
               &deg;
              </mo>
             </mrow>
            </msubsup>
            <mrow>
             <mo>
              (
             </mo>
             <mtext>
              reactants
             </mtext>
             <mo>
              )
             </mo>
            </mrow>
           </mtd>
          </mtr>
          <mtr>
           <mtd columnalign="left">
            <mtext>
             elements
            </mtext>
            <mo>
             →
            </mo>
            <mtext>
             products
            </mtext>
           </mtd>
           <mtd columnalign="right">
            <mi mathvariant="normal">
             Δ
            </mi>
            <msub>
             <mrow>
              <mi>
               H
              </mi>
             </mrow>
             <mrow>
              <mn>
               2
              </mn>
             </mrow>
            </msub>
            <mo>
             =
            </mo>
            <mo>
             +
            </mo>
            <mi mathvariant="normal">
             ΣΔ
            </mi>
            <msubsup>
             <mrow>
              <mi>
               H
              </mi>
             </mrow>
             <mrow>
              <mtext>
               f
              </mtext>
             </mrow>
             <mrow>
              <mo>
               &deg;
              </mo>
             </mrow>
            </msubsup>
            <mrow>
             <mo>
              (
             </mo>
             <mtext>
              products
             </mtext>
             <mo>
              )
             </mo>
            </mrow>
           </mtd>
          </mtr>
         </mtable>
        </mtd>
       </mtr>
       <mtr>
        <mtd>
         <mover>
          <mrow>
           <mtable columnalign="left">
            <mtr>
             <mtd columnalign="left">
              <mtext>
               reactants
              </mtext>
              <mo>
               →
              </mo>
              <mtext>
               products &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </mtext>
             </mtd>
             <mtd>
              <mi mathvariant="normal">
               Δ
              </mi>
              <msubsup>
               <mrow>
                <mi>
                 H
                </mi>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                <mtext>
                 rxn
                </mtext>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                <mo>
                 &deg;
                </mo>
               </mrow>
              </msubsup>
              <mo>
               =
              </mo>
              <mi mathvariant="normal">
               Δ
              </mi>
              <msub>
               <mrow>
                <mi>
                 H
                </mi>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                <mn>
                 1
                </mn>
               </mrow>
              </msub>
              <mo>
               +
              </mo>
              <mi mathvariant="normal">
               Δ
              </mi>
              <msub>
               <mrow>
                <mi>
                 H
                </mi>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                <mn>
                 2
                </mn>
               </mrow>
              </msub>
              <mtext>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </mtext>
             </mtd>
            </mtr>
           </mtable>
          </mrow>
          <mrow>
           <mo>
            &macr;
           </mo>
          </mrow>
         </mover>
        </mtd>
       </mtr>
      </mtable>
     </mrow>
    </math></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Even when i view it on browser, equations are overlapping. Mathjax generated Content has negative margin, that could be the reason for this.
How can i fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: We might consider this a bug so [I filed one](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1850). But the markup is very hacky. Both `mspace` and `rowline` are probably worth looking up.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger if we set strechy property to false at mo tag, then out put is correct.